# Post_logout_redirect_uri with params should work in OpenId Connect?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

This is an issue that I'm having with IdentityServer4, but I think my doubt is more related to the OIDC specs.

I'm trying to log out a site using endsession endpoint with a post_logout_redirect_uri with params in the query. An example of this is this call:

```
http://myserver.com/connect/endsession?id_token_hint=xxx&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://www.myotherweb.com/withid?userId=123&token=aspidjasijdipasd
```

where I have a userId and token in my redirect uri.

This is throwing me an "Invalid PostLogoutRedirectUri". Without the params, it's working. What I would have in my PostLogoutUris list for this example is

```
https://www.myotherweb.com/withid
```

, without the params, of course.
If we go to the OIDC specs, it says

> post_logout_redirect_uri
> OPTIONAL. URL to which the RP is requesting that the End-User's User Agent be redirected after a logout has been performed. This URL SHOULD use the https scheme and MAY contain port, path, and query parameter components; however, it MAY use the http scheme, provided that the Client Type is confidential, as defined in Section 2.1 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749], and provided the OP allows the use of http RP URIs. The value MUST have been previously registered with the OP, either using the post_logout_redirect_uris Registration parameter or via another mechanism. An id_token_hint is also REQUIRED when this parameter is included.

So I understand that query params are allowed. Looking at the IS4 source, I have arrived to the
[EndSessionRequestValidator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/EndSessionRequestValidator.cs#L142) and, after that, to [StringCollectionContainsString](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/5bcc2abbcf6c47200c4eb3b77e756f1bc0e04358/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/StrictRedirectUriValidator.cs#L26), where, if I'm seeing it correctly (I may not), it's just comparing the uri as string, without removing it's params that it could have, with our registered PostLogoutUris list. Is that ok? Am I missing something? Shouldn't it just compare the non query parameters part? Or the preregisterd url, according to those specs, should include params and all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code for IdentityServer4, `StrictRedirectUriValidator.cs` has a method

```
protected bool StringCollectionContainsString(IEnumerable<string> uris, string requestedUri)
{
    if (uris.IsNullOrEmpty()) return false;

    return uris.Contains(requestedUri, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

so obviously, your requested `post_logout_redirect_uri` is not in the collection of allowed uris so it returns false.
Despite what the specs say, IdentityServer4 seems to do a simple `Contains`.

You can override it though, as

```
public virtual Task<bool> IsPostLogoutRedirectUriValidAsync(string requestedUri, Client client)
```

is virtual, as you can see.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I say that " I think my doubt is more related to the OIDC specs.".

I could overwrite it, or even I could change the source and add it to my project, but the problem is that I don't know if it's OIDC compliant.